# Writing a section of a filename to a .txt using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code to print file names in a folder to a .txt file but I only need the first 3 words of the filenames to be copied to the .txt, how could that be achieved? I have this at the moment:

```
for %%i in (*) do (
  echo %%~ni >>list.txt
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the "words" of your filenames are divided by a space:

```
for %%A in (*) Do for /f "tokens=1-3" %%B in ("%%A") do >>list.txt Echo %%B %%C %%D
```